# How to restrict google places to restrict to only one country

Tags: angularjs, google-places-api

i am working on google maps and using "Google Places API" to search the places...
What i need is to restrict the places to only one country or only one particular region.
How to restrict google places to restrict to only one country?

Thanking you... Any answer should be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `componentRestrictions` in options to set country restrictions.

```
for example:
 {
   componentRestrictions: { country: 'IN' }
 }
```